# Set ItemName in CollectionDataContract dynamically

Tags: c#, dictionary, datacontractserializer

I have a class that implements CollectionDataContract which I want to use for various dictionaries. Every dictionary has its own ItemName and KeyName, Is it possible to set the ItemName and KeyName values dynamically? I dont want to create a class for each dictionary type.

I want to avoid this:

```
[CollectionDataContract(ItemName = "Book", KeyName = "Name")]
public class BookDictionary<TKey, TValue> : Dictionary<TKey, TValue>
{
    public BookDictionary() : base(){}
}

[CollectionDataContract(ItemName = "Product", KeyName = "ID")]
public class ProductDictionary<TKey, TValue> : Dictionary<TKey, TValue>
{
    public ProductDictionary() : base(){}
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
var obj = new ExpandoObject();
DataSet ds = GetObjectProperties() // returns dataset having the properties as key and value pair;
if (ds.Tables["BookTable"].Rows.Count > 0)
{
    foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables["BookTable"].Rows)
    {
        string KeyName = dr["KeyName"].ToString();
        string ValueName= dr["ValueName"].ToString();
        obj[KeyName] = ValueName;
    }
}
dynamic DynObj = obj;
```